# How to override the bottom navigation default icon

Tags: android, android-studio

I use the [material design bottom navigation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation-view/) and want to change the default selected icon to the one in the middle, cause that is the primary tab. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create state selector drawable and use it instead of default icon

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_hazard_selected" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_hazard_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_hazard" />
</selector>
```

menu setting:

```
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
         .......
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
```

and bottom_navigation_menu :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_board"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_board_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_board" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_feed"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_public_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_feed" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/navigation_review"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_review_black_24dp"
        android:title="@string/title_review" />

</menu>
```

Comment: Sorry, I may not have been completely clear, but I've already added my own icons. I just want to focus on the middle one.

Comment: okay, then you need to do `bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.your_menu_item);` in on view creation

Comment: please mark it as answered if everything is okay :)